# ffmpeg/batch file: input format stays in output file name

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, aac, m4a

I created this batch file to put all aac files in one directory into an m4a container. The command works so far, but every new file generated has the format of the input file in the output files name.

For example: test(.aac) is in an m4a container but is NAMED test.aac(.m4a)

Here is the .bat file:

```
for /r %%X in (*.*) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%X" "%%X.m4a"
)
pause
```

I'll be grateful for any easy solution, best regards and thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to extract just the name without extension

```
for /r %%X in (*.aac) do (
    ffmpeg -i "%%X" "%%~dpnX.m4a"
)
```

see `HELP FOR` for an explanation of the `%%~dpn` syntax, in short

> %%~X         - expands %%X removing any surrounding quotes (")
>   %%~fX        - expands %%X to a fully qualified path name
>   %%~dX        - expands %%X to a drive letter only
>   %%~pX        - expands %%X to a path only
>   %%~nX        - expands %%X to a file name only

I have also changed a bit the `FOR` selection mask to iterate only over .aac files.

Comment: wow thank you!!!

also: how do you add a output directory for the m4a containers?

Comment: edited my answer to include `~dpn` I just realized the `/R` option in the for command.

Comment: where would I place the path name?
I want all converted files in a new directory. (I'm completly new to this - it took me one night to get to even this point XD )

Comment: just specify it in output parameter of the ffmpeg command line. I'd suggest you accept this answer and post another question for your new requirement.

Comment: oh sry - forgot to accept - thanks for your reply :)